# Cordova geolocation still works after geolocation plugin is removed

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework, ngcordova

On Android, Cordova's geolocation plugin consistently takes about 6s to fix a location when other apps return a location instantly most of the time and almost never take more than 2s.

I came across this post [Phonegap geolocation sometimes not working on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383750/phonegap-geolocation-sometimes-not-working-on-android) and removed the geolocation plugin while following the instructions:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

To verify that the plugin was removed I ran the app again using `ionic run android` expecting the following call to fail

```
var posOptions = {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 10000};

$cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }, function() {
        $cordovaToast.showLongCenter('Could not get current location. Is GPS Enabled?');
    });
```

But it's working exactly as before. So I added and removed the android platform thinking the plugin might be cached:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin list

com.tiltshiftfocus.cordova.plugin.clearCache 1.0.5 "Clear Cache"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.5.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.4.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.4.0 "Toast"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
plugin.google.maps 1.3.9 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
```

And I also cleared the webview cache just in case

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

    window.cache.clear();
    ...
}
```

But it still runs exactly as before. Why is my app still able to successfully obtain a position from `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition` without the plugin? Is it using the webview's geolocation service as opposed to the plugin? How can I tell which service it's using because I suspect the app wasn't using the plugin to begin with and that this is potentially the cause of the slow gps fix.

I made some text and code changes to the app to see if any changes were being reflected and the new text & code did show up. I even completely uninstalled the app from the device before running `ionic run android` but the geolocation still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin documentation says

> This API is based on the W3C Geolocation API Specification, **and only executes on devices that don't already provide an implementation**.

Since there are so many Android devices I can not test I just include the plugin to be safe.

As for the 6 seconds vs 2 seconds, it's difficult to assess what other apps are doing without seeing their code. They may be using cached locations or such.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like crosswalk provides geolocation services: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_3/add_plugins.html